# AEM custom Workflow step: how to get ResourceResolver for initiator?

Tags: aem, sling

I'm creating a custom WorkflowProcess in AEMaaCS that does some changes on behalf of the workflow initiator. How can I get a ResourceResolver that has the rights of the workflow initator?

In the WorkflowProcess I can get a ResourceResolver e.g. like this:

```
resourceResolverFactory.getResourceResolver(
    Collections.singletonMap(JcrResourceConstants.AUTHENTICATION_INFO_SESSION,
        workflowSession.getSession())
```

but this resolver seems to be for userid `workflow-process-service`. But for security reasons I'd like to restrict the resolver to the initiators rights. How to do that? I tried this, but that throws a "Impersonation not allowed" LoginException:

```
resourceResolverFactory.getResourceResolver(
    Collections.singletonMap(ResourceResolverFactory.USER_IMPERSONATION,
        workItem.getWorkflow().getInitiator())
```

and for a `getResourceResolver` with `ResourceResolverFactory.USER` I don't have the password...
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is not possible.

I had a similar use case and ended up writing code to check initiators permissions during workflow execution instead of getting a session with initiator auth info.

Another way would be to implement your logic via a servlet instead of a workflowprocessstep (if needed, delegate batch processing to a sling job), where you can get the resourceResolver from request.